# How to create a Chart with Date / Time on the bottom Axis using iOS Charts Library?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, charts, ios-charts

I am currently working with the **iOS Library Charts** and have some issues to implement a **TimeLine** for the **x Axis**.

*Library Link: https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts*

> I have a **List of Objects** as the Input for the Chart.

```swift
let objectList : [Object] = fillObjectList()

class Object {
    var timeCreated : Date
    var value : Double
}
```

> I already **implemented a solution** where I just used the `timeCreated.timeIntervalsince1970` as the values for the x Axis. But this does not look so great.

So if some of you have some experience using iOS Charts Library, I hope you guys can think of a solution for this problem. Thanks a lot for your help in advance!

Comment: what do you mean by "this does not look so great"? what kind of UI that you want to achieve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create implementation class of IAxisValueFormatter, something like this

note: I did not compile it, so may need some correction

```
public class DateValueFormatter: NSObject, IAxisValueFormatter {
    private let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    private let objects:[Object]
    
    init(objects: [Object]) {
        self.objects = objects
        super.init()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM HH:mm"
    }
    
    public func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
        if value >= 0 && value < objects.count{
            let object = objects[Int(value)]
            return dateFormatter.string(from: object.timeCreated)
        }   
        return ""
    }
}
```

and use the formatted with this code

```
xAxis.valueFormatter = DateValueFormatter(objects: objectList)
```

edit:
you can see some example what I try using charts lib in this [repo](https://github.com/aiwiguna/ExampleCharts/tree/feature/hourly-charts)